# Issues with AMD Catalyst Driver v14.12 on Windows 8.1 x64

Tags: windows-8.1, display-driver, amd-graphics-card

I updated my video card drivers to version 14.12 for Windows 8.1 Update 1 x64. I have an AMD Radeon HD 6800 with 3 monitors. The are plugged in through the HDMI and DisplayPorts on the card.

After updating, my third monitor displays in a monochrome / B&W style. I managed to roll back to a different driver version by uninstalling the driver from the device manager and letting windows locate a driver from Windows Update. But I would like to run the Catalyst software and have the latest driver if possible, I am unable to use the Windows 8 Hulu app because it says my video driver is out of date. Also, flash, in chrome, seems to be using a lot more CPU now than it did before I had to roll back to the Windows driver.

I tried installing a previous version of Catalyst from the AMD site. First time it failed to install saying that it was unable to detect hardware. Then after a reboot, I was able to install the earlier version (14.9), but that was the same driver version that windows installed, I just now have the catalyst software also.

Comment: Are you sute the installation was done without errors? Check in the report file generated after the installation; There: C:\Program Files\ATI\CIM\Reports\Report.xml.[Installation date].xml

Comment: Yes, it installed successfully. I installed and uninstalled it 3 times. The only time it had any issue was when I tried to install an older version. I no longer have anything in those folders, as I have had to remove the software completely in order to get the 3rd monitor to be in color again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues like this can arise from conflicts with previous versions of driver files.  I've had numerous times where the AMD Catalyst Uninstall doesn't do a thorough job and ends up giving me headaches.  Here's what you can try to get a completely clean install.

1. Uninstall your current AMD Catalyst software using the AMD uninstaller (via Programs and Features)
2. Download [Display Driver Uninstaller](http://www.guru3d.com/files-details/display-driver-uninstaller-download.html) from guru3d and install it
3. Reboot into safe-mode
4. Run DDU, make sure the "Remove C:\AMD or C:\NVIDIA" box is checked, then click "Uninstall the current and previous drivers and restart the computer"
5. Install the latest catalyst drivers

Hopefully this clears up your issue.  Seems like it's helped someone with a similar issue over at [Tom's Hardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2162248/screen-color-black-white.html)

Comment: I will try this during this week and see how it goes.